# Twilio Conversations API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, rest, twilio-php, twilio-conversations

I want to use the Conversations Api to fetch all conversations of a specific user. I can't seem to find a way to do that. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

For reference, I am migrating from Programmable Chat and trying to convert this to the Conversations Api
https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/user-channel-resource#read-multiple-userchannel-resources

Comment: have you got the answer? because i have the same issue it return all the conversation

Comment: Twilio has decided not to add this feature. :(